# How to link an external library (opencv) for debugging a python ros-package in Visual-Studio-Code

Tags: python, opencv, debugging, visual-studio-code, ros

I'm writing a python node in ros-indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 and have to use opencv 3.4.6., but the ros-package [opencv3](https://wiki.ros.org/opencv3) is based on version 3.1. For building with catkin_make i have this lines in my CMakeList.txt file to link the library only if the node need it because all other nodes are linked to the earlier version and building works without error. But the node doesn't work so I want to debug the python source code with visual-studio-code.

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "home/scout/install_opencv_3.4.6")
find_package(OpenCV 3.4.6 REQUIRED)
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS"/home/scout/install_opencv_3.4.6/include")
```

So my question is how I have to setup visual-studio-code, or anything else, that the python-debugger use/link the library in my special path and not the standard path? Or is there any other solution I can debug or prepare my python script easily the library will be found?

I found some other questions or answers which mentioned the "launch.json", "settings.json" and "task.json" files but I have no idea how to treat these also not with the [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging). Maybe also [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/301015/ros-debugging-vscode-python/) can help but i don't know how.

So I hope my question is a little bit understandable, I doesn't mixed up much technical terms and anyone can help me.

Comment: Are you saying the module can't be imported and you want to know how to get VS Code and the debugger to find a custom location for the built extension module?

Comment: @BrettCannon That's sound good. I want to test my python node by debugging it in VS Code before I make it executable through catkin_make for ros. If I run the debugger in VS Code I get an error like "function xyz not found ..." because python in VS Code use version 3.1 instead of 3.4.6. But VS Code and the debugger should only find the built extension module in my custom location if I need it and otherwise the standard built extension module.

Comment: Just so you know, I have no idea what you mean by "node" or "ros" as they aren't terms used widely in the Python community.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [environment variable definitions file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file) that can [set `PYTHONPATH`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) as appropriately for your needs. And if you use the default naming scheme the debugger will pick the file up (otherwise you can [specify an env file in your `launch.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_env)).